# XMLHttpRequest not getting response after inserting in MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have surfed a lot and i have also tried all the possibilities to get this done, but still it is not working. What I am doing is, trying to insert product category using XMLHttpRequest and if recorded inserted successfully it should return true as response else false as response.

front page:

```
    <form id="form_validation" method="POST"  onsubmit="InsertCategory()">
                                <div class="form-group form-float">
                                    <div class="form-line">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="category_name" id="category_name" required>
                                        <label class="form-label">Category Name</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary waves-effect" type="submit" name="submit">SUBMIT</button>
                            </form>
<script>

        function InsertCategory()
        {
            var category_name=document.getElementById("category_name").value;
            var operation="insert";
            var url = "includes/ajax/category_master/categoryOperations.php";
            //var url = "includes/ajax/getDocuments.php";
            var params = "category_name="+category_name+"&operation="+operation;
            var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            http.onreadystatechange = function()
             {
                console.log("rs "+http.response);
                console.log(http.readyState);
                console.log(http.status);
                if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) 
                {


                }
            }
            http.open("POST", url, true);
            http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            http.send(params);
        }
    </script>
```

here is categoryOperations page

```
    <?php include_once("connection.php");
$operation=$_POST["operation"];
switch($operation)
{
    case "insert":
        $category_name=$_POST["category_name"];
        $query="insert into product_category(category_name)values(:category_name)";
        $stmt=$con->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(":category_name",$category_name);
        if($stmt->execute())
        {
            echo "true";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "false";
        }
    break;
    case "update":
    break;
    case "delete":
    break;
}
?>
```

What happens here is, all code work fine, category inserts in product_category table but i am not able to receive **true** as response. 
if I comment $stmt->execute() in categoryOperations page and echo true then it works fine, on console I get true. but if query is executed it does not return anything. 
I am not able to understand this behavior of the code.

Comment: What does the Network tab in your browser's developer tools show? Do you get a response? What is its status? Are there any errors reported in the server logs? Have you turned PHP error reporting up as high as it will go?

Comment: There are no any errors in Network tab it shows Status 200. no as i have mentioned if i execute stmt->execute() I did not get any response. On server Access Log i am getting this **::1 - - [27/Mar/2018:14:32:13 +0530] "POST /Aroj/category_master.php HTTP/1.1" 200 19907
::1 - - [27/Mar/2018:14:32:13 +0530] "POST /Aroj/includes/ajax/category_master/categoryOperations.php HTTP/1.1" 200 4**

Comment: " it shows Status 200. no as i have mentioned if i execute stmt->execute() I did not get any response" — You can't get a 200 OK response and no response at the same time!

Comment: have you tried to see if $category_name is set ? or if the query rise an error ? echo $stmt->error; ?

Comment: if you dont recive any message are you sure that $operation is set? print_r($_POST) ?

Comment: @Quentin,@Martin query executes fine. category inserts into table. that means query is executing and $_POST are set.

Comment: @Quentin ** You can't get a 200 OK response and no response at the same time!** agreed... but it's happning

Comment: @Quentin under network tab it is showing me status 200 but on console. it shows 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got Solution
The problem was, i have written

```
<form id="form_validation" method="POST"  onsubmit="InsertCategory()">
```

that was sending two request. with form as well as from xmlhttprequest.
i just removed `<form>` tag and called InsertCateory() on submit button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary waves-effect" type="submit" onClick="InsertCategory()" name="submit">SUBMIT</button>
```